# Linked List Reversal

Tags: java, linked-list

My code for linked list reversal doesn't compile. Everything seems to be logically correct.

Here is the snippet of my `LinkedList` class:

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    public static class Node {
        int  data;
        Node next;

        Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    public void display(Node n) {
        n = head;
        int ctr;

        while (n != null) {
            System.out.print(n.data +" ");
            n = n.next;
        }

        ctr = countNodes(head);
        System.out.println("The list length is "+ctr);
    }

    public Node recreverse(Node n){
        Node prev = null;
        Node temp = null;

        if (n.next == null) {
            head = n;
            head.next = prev;
            return head;
        } else {
            temp = n;
            n = n.next;

            prev = n;
            prev.next = temp;

            return n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: Have you defined function `countNodes` used in following line `ctr=countNodes(head);`?

Comment: Where is your countNodes() ?

Comment: There is no recursion in your function, at no point do you call it from itself to continue to the next node

Answer (score 0):

countNodes(Node) is not defined anywhere:

```
ctr = countNodes(head);
```

Define it and the code will compile.